# How to re-enable links in HTML after they've been disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am using a function I found googling around to disable all the links in a DIV.

It works fine, and I fully understand what it's doing.
This is it:

```
function disableLinksByElement(el) {
  if (document.getElementById && document.getElementsByTagName) {
    if (typeof(el) == 'string') {
      el = document.getElementById(el);
    }
    var anchors = el.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i=0, end=anchors.length; i<end; i++) {
      anchors[i].onclick = function() {
        return false;
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, in order to enable those links AGAIN, it's not enough to set all the "onclick" to return true, because - this is my guess - most of my links are calling JS functions, and they are not simple www links.

To summarize, this is what I am trying to do: I am using Ajax calls that, when done, fill a particular DIV with some updated HTML code.
In the meanwhile, I dim the DIV to 50% (opacity, IE8+ safe) and disable the links.
When the Ajax calls return, they un-dim the DIV and (TRY TO, WITH NO SUCCESS) re-enable the links. Be aware that the Ajax calls are truly generating "new" HTML code in the DIV, so those links should be brand new - and not blocked, but they are...

```
SAMPLE OF LINKS THAT GET DISABLED BUT NOT RE-ENABLED IN THE DIV
THESE ARE PHP-GENERATED FROM SCRATCH EACH TIME

<a class="btn" onclick="someJSfunction(2,1,50041); return false;">Do something</a>

<a href="#" onclick="someOtherJSFunction(1); return false;">
<img src="imguser/thumb_4596543689.jpg" width="25px" height="25px">
</a>
```

DISCLAIMER: I am fully aware that using jQuery it would be easier, and I am fully aware that using a client-side debugger any user could still "call" those links while the functions are executed. All the safety-checks are done on the server side, so do not worry. This is just to try to block impatient users.

Comment: And what's your relevant, minimal (simple, *representative*) HTML?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. What do you mean with relevant HTML?

Comment: What (representative) HTML does this JavaScript act upon. Or did you want us to start making guesses as to what's going on?

Comment: I'd like know if your links have already function on onclick event

Comment: I updated my question with some examples. Sorry, it took time because I do not have sources for those pages, they are PHP-generated and I do not see the source immediately, I have to open the debugger.

Comment: @InvernoMuto Yes, the links work IF I do not disable them

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use an actual `<button>` instead of a link? Then you don't care what it returns (because the default behavior is no-op), and you can simply enable/disable the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, this is the best solution I've found:

```
function disableLinksByElement(el) {
  document.getElementById(el).style.pointerEvents = "none";
  document.getElementById(el).style.opacity = 0.2;
}

function enableLinksByElement(el) {
  document.getElementById(el).style.opacity = 1;
  document.getElementById(el).style.pointerEvents = "auto";
}
```

The opacity, of course, it's just to show me what's going on.
From here:

http://caniuse.com/#search=pointerevents

I can see that the only "major" problem could be that if you use IE, you need at least IE11 to see it working, but my answer would just be "start using a real browser"...

Answer (score 1):

Take a refence to old function before to change the handler function of your hyperlink's onclick, so that you could simply restore it.

Something like this:

```js
function Test1() {
  alert('test 1');
}

function Test2() {
  alert('test 2');
}

function disableLinksByElement() {
  var hyp = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < hyp.length; i++) {
    hyp[i].Oldonclick = hyp[i].onclick;
    hyp[i].onclick = function() {
      return false;
    }
  }

}

function enableLinksByElement() {
  var hyp = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < hyp.length; i++) {
    hyp[i].onclick = hyp[i].Oldonclick;

  }

}
```

```html
<a onclick="Test1(); ">Test 1</a>
<br />
<a onclick="Test2(); ">Test 1</a>
<br />
<button onclick="disableLinksByElement()">disable</button>
<br />
<button onclick="enableLinksByElement()">enable</button>
```

Comment: I would just add a check to see if `Oldonclick` actually has something before assigning. Other than that +1